# SQLite works on device, but not in simulator. sqlite3_prepare_v2 fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm having problems with SQLite on the iPhone simulator. I've reduced it to a simple test app.  sqlite3_prepare_v2 fails.  But the real device works fine.

I created a database using sqlite3, and added it to my resources.  In my code, in viewDidLoad, I call createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded (which is a common, widely-used method, seen everywhere).  And then I call the following:-

```
- (void) queryDatabase {

    sqlite3 *database;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myDatabase.sql"];
    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; 
        const char *sqlStatement = "select * from people";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSString *firstname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *surname = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            [result appendFormat:@"%@ %@\n", firstname, surname];
        }
    [resultView setText:result];
    }
    else {
        [resultView setText:@"Problem querying database"];
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    [result release];

    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

On the simulator, sqlite3_prepare_v2 doesn't return SQLITE_OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have deleted the app icon from simulator & clean all targets before **build & run**. This will probably resolve your issues.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please tell, what error are you getting?
To find error you can  use

```
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall app from simulator and reinstall may work.